# Express $\omega(z)=z+\frac 1 z$ in the form $\omega(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to express

> $\omega(z)=z+\frac 1 z$

in the form $\omega(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

**My attempt:**

$$z:=x+yi$$

$$x+iy+\frac{1}{x+iy}$$

$$=\frac{(x+iy)^2+1}{x+iy}$$

$$=\frac{(x^2-y^2+1)+2xyi}{x+iy}$$

Now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x+iy+\frac{1}{x+iy}$$
$$=x+iy+\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$=\frac{x^3+xy^2+ix^2y+iy^3+x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$=\frac{x^3+xy^2+x+i(x^2y+y^3-y)}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$=(x+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})+i(y-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})$$
$$=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Multiply top and bottom by $x-iy$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way. Note that
$$\frac{1}{z} = \frac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}$$
Hence
$$f(x + iy) = x + iy + \frac{x - iy}{x^2 + y^2} = \left( x + \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}\right) + i \left( y - \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}\right)$$
If you really want to use your way, then simply multiply by the conjugate of your denominator and then find the real and imaginary part.